# Select certain elements from a list in python

Tags: python, arraylist

I think that this question has been asked before, although I couldn't find an answer which fit with my query exactly.

I want to print certain elements from a list, depending on the length of an input. Example:

```
if anagramLength == 2:
    print(words[0,5])
```

I found a think called **'operator.itemgetter'**, although this selects individual elements, where as I want it to select all from position 0 **TO** position 5 (not position 0 **AND** position 5).

Thanks!

Comment: You mean `words[0:5]`?

Comment: ya thats want he meant i think

Comment: I did mean that. Thanks... !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the correct slicing:

```
words[0:5]
```

That is, replace the `,` by `:`

```
if anagramLength == 2:
    print(words[0:5])
```

---

The usage `words[0,5]`, produces an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

To understand why the error is caused, do the following:

```
>>> 0,5
(0, 5)
```

See, it is a `tuple`. You can't slice a string with a tuple, but an integer :)

Comment: So simple yet I didn't even try it. Thank you

Comment: I realised you said tick not upvote after I replied. Cheers :)

Comment: @WillLevine sure :) i think words[0,5] produces an error. did it? do you want to know why?

Comment: it did. how come?

Comment: @WillLevine i'll add that to the answer

Comment: ahhhhh. understood. i have to admit i was confused when I saw it so thank you for that :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`slicing`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html).

The syntax is fairly simple:

```
words[start:stop]
```

Will print elements from `start` index to `stop` index, in your case:

```
print(words[0:5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slicing`:

```py
if anagramLength == 2:
    print(words[:5])
```